# How to write a document.querySelector for the following code

Tags: javascript, queryselector

I'm having difficulty writing the `document.querySelector` for the following code. Currently I've written this code as `querySelector` but it does not encompass everything...

Please help me improve this, thank you.

**Edit:** as there seemed to be some confusion, let me elaborate. I would like all the elements, from div, a, img, *everything* to be encompassed in the querySelector.

```js
var areaa = document.querySelector("#menu #envelope #links");
```

```html
<div id="menu">Click here to browse the internet.
 <div id="envelope">
  <div id="links" >
   <div>
    <a id="g" class="redirect">
     <img id="google" src="assets/google.png" />
    </a>
   </div>
   <div style="width: 20%;"></div>
   <div>
    <a id="s" class="redirect">
     <img id="sava" src="assets/Logo_Sava.png"/>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Edit 2** - as more code was required (the href elements are removed / added as needed)...

```
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
var areaa = document.querySelectorAll(".areaa");

menu.addEventListener("mouseenter", addHref);
//areaa.addEventListener("mouseleave", remHref);

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(){
    if(this != areaa){
        remHref();
    }
});

menu.addEventListener("click", addHref);
document.addEventListener("click", function (){
    if (this != areaa){
        remHref();
    }
});

var g = document.getElementById("g");
var s = document.getElementById("s");

function remHref (){
    if (g.hasAttribute("href")){
        g.removeAttribute("href");
    }
    if (s.hasAttribute("href")){
        s.removeAttribute("href");
    }
}

function addHref (){
    setTimeout(activate, 250);
}

function activate (){
    document.getElementById("g").setAttribute("href", "https://www.google.com");
    document.getElementById("s").setAttribute("href", "https://www.example.com");
}
```

Comment: What element exactly are you trying to get here? The `#link`?

Comment: What do you mean by *"it does not encompass everything"*? Could you elaborate there?

Comment: I would like the whole code listed to be encompassed into the `querySelector`. So all the divs, a, img. Everything

Comment: All I can gather is that you'd like to select the `#menu` instead, which would simply be: `document.getElementById('menu')`

Comment: Re edit: This is reading like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What are you trying to accomplish by selecting all these elements?

Comment: I would like to add an event listener which removes the href element whenever the mouse moves outside this area

Comment: @DrDoom, you do not have any element with *href* attribute!!!

Answer (score 1):

you might want to add a class to all elements you want to be captured, then use document.querySelectorAll

```
var areaa = document.querySelectorAll(".my-class");
```

html shoud look like this:

```
<div id="menu" class="my-class">Click here to browse the internet.
<div id="envelope" class="my-class">
    <div id="links" class="my-class">
        <div>
            <a id="g" class="redirect">
                <img class="my-class" id="google" src="assets/google.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 20%;"></div>
        <div>
            <a id="s" class="redirect">
                <img id="sava" src="assets/Logo_Sava.png"/>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select everything you can use the below:

`var areaa = document.querySelectorAll("#menu #envelope #links *");`

If you want to be more specific you can do the following (the code below will select all of the anchor tags and images inside `#links`):

`var areaa = document.querySelectorAll("#menu #envelope #links a, #menu #envelope #links img");`

Comment: `querySelector` will only retrieve one match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **querySelectorAll**

The Document method querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.
Learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

You can use it like this:

```
var areaa = document.querySelectorAll('*');
```

This will return **all** items.
You can replace *document* with the container if you want to restrict this to a specific *div*.

Answer (score 0):

2 things, either add a class to every div

```
<div id="menu" class="area">Click here to browse the internet.
    <div id="envelope" class="area">
        <div id="links" class="area" >
            <div>
                <a id="g" class="redirect">
                    <img id="google" src="assets/google.png" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 20%;"></div>
            <div>
                <a id="s" class="redirect">
                    <img id="sava" src="assets/Logo_Sava.png"/>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and select all divs by

```
let areaa = getElementsByClassName("area");
```

or you can use `document.querySelectorAll("yourclassname")` to access all divs of that class name